# How to call C function through JNA with 2d pointer?

Tags: java, arrays, c, structure, jna

Here is the signature of my C function :

```
typedef struct myitem_s {
    int a;
    int b;
} myitem_t;

int get_items(myitem_t** items);
```

The usage in a C program is::

```
myitem_t* items = NULL;
int n = = get_items(&items);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    myitem_t* item = &items[i];
}
```

`items` is allocated in the `get_items()` function and contains one or more `myitem_t` elements.

From Java code I have succeeded in doing this:

```
Memory itemsPtr = new Memory(Native.POINTER_SIZE);
Pointer p = itemsPtr.getPointer(0);
int n = CLibrary.INSTANCE.get_items(p);
```

The `n` value is valid, `itemsPtr` is updated so I suggest value is good also. Now I have no idea of how to use it. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: wouldn't you have to get the pointer *after* you call get_items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but you're using a lot of lower level functions when JNA has some higher level constructs.

First, the C `struct` can be represented by a JNA `Structure`.

```java
@FieldOrder({ "a", "b" })
class MyitemT extends Structure {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

Since the native code is handling the memory allocation, all you need is the pointer to it.  Rather than a pointer-sized memory allocation, you probably want a `PointerByReference`.

```java
PointerByReference pbr = new PointerByReference();
```

The key methods you want from this are `getPointer()` (the pointer to the pointer) and `getValue()` (the pointed-to value).

Given the above, pass the pointer-to-the-pointer to the method, which will allocate the memory and populate the value.

Using the mapping you already have (not shown but inferred):

```java
int n = CLibrary.INSTANCE.get_items(pbr.getPointer());
```

However, you should actually map `get_items()` to take a `PointerByReference` argument and then you can just pass `items` directly.

At this point, `items.getValue()` is a `Pointer` to the start of your array of structures. Additional items would be at offsets of the pointer value based on the size of the structure (`item.size()`).  There are multiple ways of getting at that.

In your case since you know you just have pairs of ints, you could skip the whole "structure" part and just use `items.getValue().getInt(0)` and `items.getValue().getInt(4)` for the first pair; 8 and 12 for the second pair, etc.  But even better, just `items.getValue().getIntArray(0,n*2);` fetches an array of integers, just pull them out by pairs.

But that takes advantage of internal details. Probably the most JNA-ish choice is to use `Structure.toArray()` to create an array of your `MyitemT` structures. If you include a pointer constructor and create the initial structure using that pointer, `Structure.toArray()` uses that existing mapping. You can then `read()` into your array:

```java
MyItemT item = new MyItemT(pbr.getValue());
MyItemT[] items = (MyItemT[]) item.toArray(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    items[i].read();
    // now you can see items[i].a and items[i].b
}
```

Don't forget to eventually release the native-allocated memory however the API tells you to!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. `useMemory()` is protected, I did it this way : `MyItemT item = new MyItemT(pointer.getValue()); MyItemT[] items = (MyItemT[]) item.toArray(n); for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { items[i].read(); }`

Comment: You can override useMemory in your own structure, though... but actually your solution is an even better option. I'll update my answer to include it.